# How do I align the cube in which shadows are computed with the view frustrum? ("View Space aligned frustum")

Tags: opengl, projection, shadow-mapping, view

Short and concise:

Given 8 world space positions that form a cube of arbitrary size, position and orientation and given an arbitrary light direction.

How do I compute the View and Projection matrix for a directional light, such that the shadows are computed in exactly and only this cube?

Edit: Clarification: I want to create Shadow Maps, in the way, that Crytek calls "View Space aligned" (http://www.crytek.com/download/Playing%20with%20Real-Time%20Shadows.pdf page 54-55), so I want that the cube in which shadows are computed is aligned with the view frustrum. How do I achieve that, when I have already have the 8 world space positions of a cube, around the view frustrum?